# NPOI Multiple Sheets Error

Tags: excel, npoi

I am trying to create an EXCEL XLSX file in a .net webcontext.

I tried this code but as soon as I add more than 1 sheet my excel becomes corrupt.

I am using NPOI 2.1.3

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
wb.CreateSheet("sheet1");
wb.CreateSheet("sheet 2);
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
wb.Write(memoryStream);
memoryStream.Close();
var buffer = memoryStream.GetBuffer();
response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
response.BinaryWrite(templateOutput);
```

Answer (score 0):

When I use a FileStream the functionality works. (Multiple sheets)